# How to run Matlab compiled Java function?

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have compiled a Matlab script to Java with Matlab compiler SDK.
Everything worked fine. Matlab generated a Jar.file and i included it into my Java Project in eclipse.
Now my Problem is, the matlab script contains a complex algorithm function.
This function can be now called in Java.
I need to read 10 csv files with each containing 10.000 rows with 4 columns of data and pass now the same arguments to the java function as i did in matlab.

The way my csv files are: 4 columns, 10.000 rows.

```
a x y z
1 3 4 5
4 4 5 6
. . . .
```

readsfirst the data in a seperate function in the variables.Also get length of a.

```
[a,x,y,z] = readData(['csv\' files(1).name]);
sizeOfa=length(a);
```

after i call my algorithm function 3 times with different columns and also pass the size of a.

```
   algorithm(a,x,sizeOfa);
   algorithm(a,y,sizeOfa);
   algorithm(a,z,sizeOfa);
```

after this the definition of my algorithm comes.

```
function y= algorithm(x,y,sizeofX)
   do some stuff...
   end
```

Now my question:

my values read from csv file are stored in Matlab in a 10000*1 Matrix.
If i want to call the same function now in Java.
What should i pass in to my function?
I can read my values a, x, y, z all in seperate arrays.
but an array is 1*10000.
Can i just pass an array? The readfile function was not compiled to java, i just compiled my algorithm function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions for my problem.

**MATLAB Solution**

My Matlab function used a 10000*1 Array. It is a Matrix like this

```
1
2
3
4
..
10000
```

An Java array passed to compiled function would be different. It looks like this

```
1 2 3 4 .. 10000
```

Now what did to solve this was, i tranponse the arguments passed to my matlab function.

```
   function y = algorithm(a,z,sizeOfa)
    {
      a=a'; // transpose 
      z=z'; //transpose
       ...
         //your stuff

    }
```

Now if i pass my array into my java function, the array is internally transpose to a matrix.

EDIT:
Better Solution found

**Java Solution**

```
double[] t;  // your Double Array

int tSize= t.length; // get Size

MWNumericArray result;

result= MWNumericArray.newInstance(new int[]{tSize,1},t,MWClassID.DOUBLE);
```

Pass result to your function, it is converted to a n*1 Array, where n is the size of your array.